# Impossible to acces to value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a rails newbie !

I would like to know why in that different case, one work, one doesn't.

```
### in my controller ###
def watch_randurl
  # @dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand])
  @dat = Video.find(1)
end
```

With `find(1)`, I have my database and in my view this work!

```
### in my view ###
<%= @dat.url_rand %> <br>
```

but with the `where` I have a 
`undefined method 'url_rand' for <Video::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fcbfeece1c8>`

Ps: sorry for my english :/
Of course, I need this work with a where.

SOLVE with : `Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand]).first` 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But with the where i have a undefined method 'url_rand' for
>   Video::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fcbfeece1c8

`where` returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, so in that case, you need to modify `@dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand])`, to `@dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand]).first`

***or***

You can iterate over `@dat` like below, without changing the value of `@dat`

```
<% @dat.each do |dat| %>
  <%= dat.url_rand %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i need to use the syntax of my where, i need to take my rand_url with my params[rand_url]

Comment: the find(1) is just to see if i can access to my db data

Comment: @RedWine If you are talking about this `@dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand])` then change it to `@dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand]).first`

Comment: @RedWine Please accept my answer by ticking it green :)

Comment: as you can up my question :p

Answer (score 0):

`@dat = Video.find(1)` returns a single Vedio object that's why you can use `@dat.url_rand`.

But when you use where like `@dat = Video.where(url_rand: params[:url_rand])` you will get an array of objects in `@dat`. So @dat will be an array of objects here.

In this case, you'll have to follow [Pavan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2346461/pavan) advise and do something like this:

`@dat.first.url_rand` or `@dat[0].url_rand`

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a way to get a record based on a condition you could use *find_by*.

**find_by(*args)** [source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

Finds the first record matching the specified conditions.

In your case you could use:

```
@video = Video.find_by(url_rand: params[:url_rand])
```

@video would be the first video matching the condition.